# How to create a Twig JS function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, twig, twig.js

I'm using **twig js template for node js 13.6.0 with express 3**

I used before twig for php and since i passed on twig js i'm searching how to create a function that I can use inside my twig code in php it was :

```
> $twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction("name", function(){
      //code
  }));
```

Do someone know how to create a twig js function??

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the wiki github of the project, you have several examples there [Twig Wiki](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js/wiki)

Comment: yes i looked and it has nothing about that

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js/wiki/Extending-twig.js ?